# Binary search trees Max and Min Height based on number of nodes

Tags: data-structures

I am working on a data structures assignment.  The question is to find the Min height and max height for a 100 node tree.  Please correct me if I am wrong but the Min height I believe is Log(base 2)(Number of Nodes).  I can't seem to find the formula for the max height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the nodes have data or only the leaves?

Hint for the max: it would be completely unbalanced which would pretty much be a linked list of the nodes (e.g. all items on one side only).

See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6277/why-is-the-minimum-height-of-a-binary-tree-log-2n1-1

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense